A trick to prove existence of Haar measure
Let $G$ be an abelian compact and separable group, then there exists a unique Radon measure $\mu$ such that
$\mu(g A) = \mu(A)$ for each $g \in G$ and Borel set $A$
$\mu(G) = 1$
The proof of this theorem is pretty technical and therefore many books avoid showing it, I've came up with a simple ergodic-like argument that shows the existence, I would like to show the uniqueness in a similar simple way.
The argument :
Let $M(G)$ denote the space of Radon measures $\mu$ for which $\mu(G) = 1$. By the separability of $G$ I know that for each sequence $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ there exist a measure $\mu \in M(G)$ and a subsequence $(\mu_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\mu_{n_k} \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$.
Let $\{g_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a dense sequence in $G$, consider for each $n,l$ the measure
$$\mu^{(n)}_l := \frac{1}{n^l}\sum_{j_1,\dots,j_l = 1}^{n}{\delta_{g^{j_1}_1 \cdot \dots \cdot g^{j_l}_l} }$$
Then there exists a measure $\mu_l$ for which a subsequence of $\mu^{(n)}_l$ weakly star converges to, but then $\mu_l$ is invariant by the action of $g_1,g_2,\dots,g_l$.
There exists a measure $\mu$ for which a subsequence of $\mu_l$ weakly star converges to, but then $\mu$ is invariant by the action of $g_j$ for any $j$, but by density $\mu$ is invariant by the action of any $g \in G$.
Is my argument correct? Can I show uniqueness in a similar fashion?

Concerning uniqueness you may use $$\iint\limits_{G\times G} f(xy)d\mu_1(x)d\mu_2(y)$$

Sorry for my comments. I have overlooked the commutativity assumption. I think your idea can be applied for compact separable groups, not necessarily commutative.

@RyszardSzwarc I was thinking the same thing, but I should find an expression like $$\frac{1}{n^l}\sum_{j_1,\dots,j_l = 1}^{n}{\delta_{g^{j_1}_1 \cdot \dots \cdot g^{j_l}_l } }$$ that does the trick for non-commutative groups

@Paul for a compact Abelian group one can argue quite simply using the Markov Kakutani fixed point theorem

I would try with $$\mu_l^{(n)}={1\over l^n}\sum_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n=1}^l\delta_{g_{i_1}g_{i_2}\ldots g_{i_n}}$$ and the limit with respect to $n.$
